# mpd/ncmpcpp music database synchronization with iPod Classic (possible)?

Tags: sync, ipod, mpd, ncmpcpp

Is there any option/possibility, to synchronize my mpd/ncmpcpp music database as it is organized natively through ncmpcpp (mainly playlists) with an iPod Classic.

Can someone please shed some light on this matter and a tutorial (if available) would be much appreciated!!